# $row how to get all data into vars

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an page the script is done it lists Name and Points in a table. But when i gonna do the design it will be to hard to do it with "echo". So i am woundering if i can get this into vars insted that i can just use  in a html file.

Table look like this

Name | Points | Date

What i want is to make a var for the 10 first name rows and a var for the 10 first point rows.

Like

```
$top1n = $row[0]'name'
$top1p = $row[0]'points'
$top2n = $row[1]'name'
$top2p = $row[1]'points'
$top3n = $row[2]'name'
$top3p = $row[2]'points'
$top4n = $row[3]'name'
$top4p = $row[3]'points'
```

And so on...

etc.

See my script below

```
echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Tokens</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultbtm )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['Name'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['points'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or another templating engine may be what you are looking for.

Comment: What you want to do is coding horror.  You will have ~20 dynamically named variables that relate to the same thing.  This is exactly what an array is for.  If you look at my answer (there are a ton of other ways to do this), you will have all of your info in two arrays `$names` and `$points` (this can be one array).  Instead of doing `echo $top4n;` or `echo $top1p;` you can just do `echo $names[3];` and `echo  $points[0];`.  There is no difference except the array is much cleaner and more logical.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$names = array();
$points = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultbtm)) {
    $names[] = $row['Name'];
    $points[] = $row['tokens'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($names);
print_r($points);
echo '</pre>';
```

Not 100% sure if this is what you were looking for, but the `$names` and `$points` variables will be arrays containing the Names and Tokens (respectively) from your mysql result set.

Side note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 due to security issues.  If you are able to it is strongly recommended you switch to [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: See my comment on your question, that is referring to your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: (no need to create so many variables)

```
$str = "<table border='1'>";

$str .= "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Tokens</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultbtm )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    $str .= "<tr>";
    $str .= "<td>".$row['Name']."</td><td>".$row['points']."</td>";
    $str .= "</tr>"; 
} 

$str .= "</table>";
echo $str;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `extract`

```
    echo "<table border='1'>";

    echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Tokens</th> </tr>";
    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    $c = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultbtm )) {
        ${'top'.$c.'n'} = $name;
        ${'top'.$c.'p'} = $points;
        $c++;

        // Print out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr><td>$Name</td><td>$tokens</td></tr>"; 
    } 

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I will explain it a bit better.